# Syntax error in <%= if flash[:notice]%> Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

The probleming code:

```html
<%= if flash[:notice] %>
  <div class="notification is-primary global-notification">
    <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= if flash[:alert] %>
  <div class="notification is-danger global-notification">
    <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And when running my server the following error drops:
[image]

Already changed the syntax to: `if (flash[:notice])`. But still, drop this. Any idea?

Comment: You need `<%` and not `<%=` because you are not outputting anything, you want to write a statement.

Comment: This works fine. Didn't know that, so for example when wold you use <%=? Thanks for the answer

Comment: When you want to print something. (e.g. `<%= notice %>`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```rb
<%= if flash[:notice] %>
```

The above code should be:

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
```

**Note**

`<% %>` - Executes the ruby code within the brackets.

`<%= %>` - Prints something into ERB file.